# Why is beautifulsoup not parsing a simple Wikipedia Table

Tags: beautifulsoup

To help fight covid19 here in the Philippines, I'm trying to do data analysis. My data source is table of incidences in Wikipedia. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_the_Philippines

Tried to get table in python with Beautiful soup but I cannot seem to get the content of the columns [Facility of admission or consultation, Had recent travel history abroad]. See screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of dataframe result]

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code: (can also be found here https://github.com/gio888/covid19_ph2/blob/master/covid_import_from_wikipedia.ipynb)

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:2019%E2%80%9320_coronavirus_pandemic_data/Philippines_medical_cases_summary"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable')

n_columns = 0
n_rows=0
column_names = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
   td_tags = row.find_all('td')
   if len(td_tags) > 0:
      n_rows+=1
      if n_columns == 0:
         n_columns = len(td_tags)

   th_tags = row.find_all('th') 
   if len(th_tags) > 0 and len(column_names) == 0:
      for th in th_tags:
         column_names.append(th.get_text())

columns = column_names if len(column_names) > 0 else range(0,n_columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns,index= range(0,n_rows))

row_marker = 0
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
   column_marker = 0
   columns = row.find_all('td')
   for column in columns:
      df.iat[row_marker,column_marker] = column.get_text()
      column_marker += 1
   if len(columns) > 0:
      row_marker += 1

for col in df:
   try:
      df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
   except ValueError:
      pass

df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_the_Philippines")

items = [["yes", "Yes"], ["no", "No"], [
    "TBA", "TBA"], ["status-d", "Died"], ["status-r", "Recovered"], ["status-a", "Admitted"]]

for item in items:
    script = (
        "document.querySelectorAll('.{}').forEach((element) => element.innerHTML = '{}')".format(*item))
    driver.execute_script(script)


df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[2]
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)

driver.quit()
```

Output: [View Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/829e9d8808f1b3cef058466e41dcb207/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I actually did that first but it's not capturing the data in the columns I mentioned.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks for this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:2019%E2%80%9320_coronavirus_pandemic_data/Philippines_medical_cases_summary"

css_content = {
    'status-a': 'Admitted',
    'status-r': 'Recovered',
    'status-d': 'Died',
    'yes':'Yes',
    'no': 'No',
    'tba':'TBA',
    "covid-sticky":'skip_header'
}

def Check_att(source,value,attribute='class'):
    # <tag att='value'> <td class='x'>
    if col_value : return col_value
    if value in source.attrs.get(attribute, []) :
        return css_content.get(value,'')
    return ''


url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_the_Philippines'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable')


column_names = [col_name.text.rstrip('\n').strip() for col_name in table.select('tr.covid-sticky > th')]
n_rows       = len(table.select('tr > td'))
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names,index= range(0,n_rows))
for row_index,row in enumerate(table.find_all('tr')[1:],0):
    # if Check_att(row,"covid-sticky") :continue        
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    for col_index , column in enumerate(columns,0):
        col_value     = ''
        col_value     = Check_att(column,'status-a')
        col_value     = Check_att(column,'status-r')
        col_value     = Check_att(column,'status-d')
        col_value     = Check_att(column,'yes')
        col_value     = Check_att(column,'no')
        col_value     = Check_att(column,'tba')
        if not col_value :
            col_value = column.get_text().rstrip('\n').strip()
        df.iat[row_index,col_index] = col_value




for col in df:
   try:
      df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
   except ValueError:
      pass

print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks for this. Much appreciated.

Comment: @gio888 you are welcome , if it helped you , accept it